# Inverse Laplacian of xarray

Tags: python, data

my question is related to calculating the inverse Laplacian of a xarray. Specifically, I want to solve the equation ∇^2 s = h+r+e for s in Python (where ∇^2 denotes the laplacian). Here, s is an xarray with units (ensemble members, time, latitude, longitude) which includes both positive and negative values at the different gridpoints.

I found the sympy.integrals.inverse_laplace_transform() function but this uses a function as an input which is not what I am after. I also looked at the pyshtool package which might be of help here (see my attempt below).

I think that I probably would need to use spherical harmonics, then the property that their derivatives become multiplications and then reverse transform back afterwards (but I am not too familiar with these operations). So far, I tried to create a spherial harmonics grid and then calculate the coefficients but I am getting the error that there is a "grid resolution mismatch" and besides that I am really unsure if my attempt is even correct so far.

Would anyone have an idea how I can calculate the inverse laplacian of my xarray s?
Any help much appreciated!

```
from pyshtools import SHGrid, MakeGridDH
from pyshtools.expand import SHExpandDH
import xarray as xr

s = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(3, 10, 90, 180), dims=("ensemble_members", "time", "latitude", "longitude"))


# Create a grid using SHGrid
grid_s = SHGrid.from_array(s.mean(dim=["ensemble_members", "time"]).values)

# Ensure the data type is compatible (e.g., convert to float64) because I kept on getting the error "'DHRealGrid' object has no attribute 'astype'"
grid_data = grid_s.data.astype(np.float64)

# My attempt to calculate the coefficients from the spherical harmonics --> this does not work and gives me the error "grid resolution mismatch"
coeffs_hre = SHExpandDH(grid_data, sampling=30)

############
# This was my idea how to continue but the code before does not actually work
# Calculate the inverse Laplacian
#coeffs_inverse_laplacian = coeffs_hre / coeffs.lap()

# Reverse transform to the original grid
#grid_inverse_laplacian = MakeGridDH(coeffs_inverse_laplacian)
#s_inverse_laplacian = xr.DataArray(grid_inverse_laplacian.data, dims=("latitude", "longitude"))
```